# Make a Chrome extension call a Windows Service

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, windows-services

My goal is call a Windows Service, passing a string as parameter, from a google chrome extension.

Is it possible? Any samples available?

Comment: -1 You want to call a DLL, or a service. Which is it? And which type of extension are you wanting to build? Have you ever done any programming before? What do you know how to do? Have you written an extension before? And what is this DLL or service? Do they exist yet? Please let us know what you know, and what you have tried?

Comment: With no activity from the author, and taking into account the useful existing answer, I took the liberty to edit the title/tags to match the question text and the answer. I understand it's a questionable thing to do, but in this case this was proposed as a duplicate target based on title alone. I'm trying to remove that confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same question on Codeproject and the user kbrandwijk has solved my problem.

Here is his answer. I'm posting here to help anyone who have the same question.

---

The only part of the API that allows you to communicate outside of the sandbox since NPAPI is phased out, is the [Native Messenging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging). This approach would however, require you to install a host and register it in Chrome.

This host can be a small C# program that actually talks to the Windows Service. Check the example here: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/